# Finding the real part of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers

I have to find the real part of the complex number given below

$((x^2+2x+y^2+y) +i(x+2y+2))/((x+2)^2+y^2)$

Since I am only concerned with the real part, I wrote it separately, giving me the below expression

$
((x^2+2x+y^2+y)/((x+2)^2+y^2) 
$

The answer given for this question is 1 and can someone tell me why is it 1

Comment: can you post the original Problem please?

Comment: Note that you have two expressions here and no equations.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner original problem as in?

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ supposed to be real numbers, or complex ones?

Comment: @JohnHughes  x and y are really numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is no other information given in the problem, the given answer is just wrong.  For example, if $x=0$ and $y=0$, the given complex number is $(0+2i)/4=i/2$ with real part $0$, not $1$.  Your answer is correct as long as you know that $x$ and $y$ are both real.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy to separate real and imaginary part in above expression. And i think you can leave as it is.

Comment: Consider the case $x = -2, y = 1$; your answer is $2$, but the book's answer is $1$. You are correct, and the book is mistaken.